# Submitting revised manuscript long before due date

Tags: mathematics, peer-review, journals, paper-submission

I have submitted a manuscript five months ago and received the first decision of the journal which was "Major revision". The first reviewer recommended accept after major revision. His comments were minor except two comments that suggested we address some questions, which I have decided to leave to our future research due to their complexity. The comments of the other reviewer were all minor. I was able to address all the reviewers comments and justified the reason I left the two major comments of the first reviewer to my future research.

However, the issue is that the due date of submitting the revision is still two months from now and I'm asking:

Would it give a bad impression to the editor and referees if I submitted the revision only one week after receiving the decision?

Comment: What's the question? There's no question mark in what you've written.

Comment: The question has been edited.

Comment: " The first reviewer recommended accept after major revision." So the referee thought that a major revision of the paper was suitable for the journal and implicitly that the paper in its present form is not suitable. You have now made some minor revisions. (And explained that you intend to keep the good stuff for later papers .... ) I wouldn't be surprised if you now got from the editor "not in present form although willing to consider a new version dealing with the issues previously raised".

Answer (score 6):

You are taking a risk, probably a large one, not by submitting quickly, but by not addressing one of the reviewers comments in this paper and leaving it for future work. Given that, a quick response is justified, but it leaves you vulnerable to a rejection.

If the editor, ultimately, decides that the work is incomplete for not addressing those "major revision" comments then you could well be rejected.

If you have a couple of months, then I'd suggest that you see what you can do about addressing those comments directly and explore, at least, a major revision.

The editor probably isn't going to make final decisions merely on voting by the referees, but on the nature of the comments they make and how you address them. Risky.

Comment: I  should mention that the reason why I left the two comments is that they are still open questions and merit to be treated independently, due to their complexity (I have added the suitable references justifying this claim for simpler cases) on one hand and due to the length of the current manuscript on the other.  Moreover, in the first manuscript, it was mentioned that the focus will not be on the topic of these questions. Note that there were 8 other comments of the first reviewer who have been addressed accordingly as well as all the other comments of the other referee.

Comment: That may be enough for the editor unless the other reviewer disagrees with the difficulty/complexity of settling the open questions. Take a look at that, at least, but you may be fine.